# Using Recursion tree to solve recursive equations

Tags: math, computer-science

() = ( − 1) +  (n/2) + n
How can I solve this recursive equation with recursion tree?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Have you tried... *drawing the recursion tree?*

Comment: Thanks;) Should I draw both T(n-1) and T(n/2)?